# How to change the Magento Directory structure for images when Importing

Tags: magento-1.9, import, magmi, product-images

What I'm trying to do is change the default folder structure of imported images.
For example when you import an image magento defaults the directory structure to the first and second letter of the image to create the directory structure under /media/catalog/product/X/Y/XYimage.jpg

I want to be able to modify the core to allow me to change it to something like:
/media/catalog/product/SKU/XYZ/SKUXYZimage.jpg
hence the first 3 letters are the top level of the directory and the next 3 letters are the second level of the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple workaround and just tested over 60k products.
 install Magmi (Search Google).Navigate to `\magmi\plugins\extra\itemprocessors\imageprocessor`
open `imageitattributeemprocessor.php` with your favorite editor go to and replace 496 to 505 with this small modification.

```
$i1 = $bimgfile[0];
    $i2 = $bimgfile[1];
    $i3 = $bimgfile[2];
    $i4 = $bimgfile[3];
    $i5 = $bimgfile[4];
    $i6 = $bimgfile[5];
    // magento image value (relative to media catalog)
    $impath = "/$i1$i2$i3/$i4$i5$i6/$bimgfile";
    // target directory;
    $l2d = "media/catalog/product/$i1$i2$i3/$i4$i5$i6";
```

As you can see I chose on $impath to set my structure up as 
`"/$i1$i2$i3/$i4$i5$i6/$bimgfile"` Translated sku123456.jpg would be `media/catalog/product/sku/123/sku123456.jpg`[image] 
Sorry for the crude drawing (I'm New at this)
Always remember if you upgrade Magmi this can be over written so always back up your files.

Answer (score 1):

Backtracing the code

1. `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::addImageToMediaGallery`
2. `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media::addImage`
3. `Varien_File_Uploader::getDispretionPath`

It seems that the path is build here. Since you can't override a Varien file from a custom module you will have to copy the file to `app/code/local/Varien/File/Uploader.php`. There you can change the way the path is build.

However, this will not only affect products in that case. You might want to override `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media::addImage` from a custom module to limit the scope of the changes to just products. So instead of calling `Mage_Core_Model_File_Uploader::getDispretionPath` on line `286` you might want to change that line into calling a custom method for returning the path.

Comment: Thank You for your input that is leading me in the right direction, but I think I found an easier way to do it. I will test and report my findings shortly